# Count people in companies in tree structure

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

Hello I have a structure table with companies_id(PK) and parent_companies_id(FK) column and people table with companies_id (FK) and people_id(PK). Some people can be in different companies. I want to count quantity of each company including child.

```
+------------------+-------------------------+
| companies_id(PK) | parent_companies_id(FK) |
+------------------+-------------------------+
|              101 | null                    |
|              102 | 101                     |
|              103 | 101                     |
|              104 | 103                     |
|              105 | 103                     |
|              106 | 104                     |
+------------------+-------------------------+

+---------------+------------------+
| people_id(PK) | companies_id(FK) |
+---------------+------------------+
|           001 |              101 |
|           002 |              102 |
|           003 |              102 |
|           004 |              104 |
|           005 |              105 |
|           006 |              106 |
+---------------+------------------+

CREATE TABLE COMPANY
  ( Company_ID Integer,
    Parent_ID Integer
  );

CREATE TABLE PEOPLE
  ( People_ID VARCHAR(3),
    Company_ID Integer
  );

INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (101,NULL);
INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (102,101);
INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (103,101);
INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (104,103);
INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (105,103);
INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (106,104);

INSERT INTO PEOPLE VALUES ('001',101);
INSERT INTO PEOPLE VALUES ('002',102);
INSERT INTO PEOPLE VALUES ('003',102);
INSERT INTO PEOPLE VALUES ('004',104);
INSERT INTO PEOPLE VALUES ('005',105);
INSERT INTO PEOPLE VALUES ('006',106);
```

The result have to be next

```
+--------------+------------+
| companies_id | people_qnt |
+--------------+------------+
|          101 |          6 |
|          102 |          2 |
|          103 |          3 |
|          104 |          2 |
|          105 |          1 |
|          106 |          1 |
+--------------+------------+
```

Comment: What DBMS did you use?

Comment: @D-Shih I used Oracle

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that your `structure` table (which I called "struct") has a row for every company. If that isn't true, you should use something different for the driving table.

```
select struct.companies_id, count(people_id)
from struct
inner join people on people.companies_id in 
        (select s2.companies_id
         from struct s2
         start with s2.companies_id = struct.companies_id
         connect by prior s2.companies_id = s2.parent_companies_id)
group by struct.companies_id
order by 1
;
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/67a428/2)